# SQL 2008 Math is failing in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  I have a table of interest rates.  I've manually verified that the data I'm trying to select does exist in the table.

This returns records:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [MyTable]
  WHERE [Rate]=3.99/100
```

This does not return records:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [MyTable]
  WHERE [Rate]*100=3.99
```

Here's the really messed up part: As far as I can tell, this only happens when the Rate field contains a value of `.035`, `.03625`, or `.0399`.

Can anyone tell me why the second instance does not work?  This table does have an ID field (PK), and the `Rate` field is `FLOAT`.  Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use decimal not floats for interest rates. `float` is imprecise and you encounter rounding errors as you have discovered!

On my machine

```
WITH [MyTable]([Rate])
     AS (SELECT CAST(.0399 AS FLOAT))
SELECT [Rate] * 100,
       CASE
         WHEN [Rate] * 100 = 3.99 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
       END AS [= 3.99],
       CASE
         WHEN [Rate] * 100 > 3.989999999999999 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
       END AS [> 3.989999999999999],
       CASE
         WHEN [Rate] * 100 < 3.99 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
       END AS [< 3.99]
FROM   [MyTable]
```

Returns

```
                       = 3.99 > 3.989999999999999 < 3.99
---------------------- ------ ------------------- ------
3.99                   N      Y                   Y
```

Obligatory Link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I still work with PhD bearing developers who can't understand what FLOAT *is* and *is not* suitable for.

Comment: Of course you're right.  I, of course, am kicking myself now.  I even came across it here (if anyone else is looking): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx

Thank you, have a great day!